# DBMS table not found error adding PostGIS layer in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, postgis, arcmap, arcgis-10.4

I imported some shapefiles to a postgis database. In QGIS it works fine, however in ArcMap 10.4 not yet. I added postgreSQL as a database connection in ArcMap. I can also see the postgis layers in the ArcCatalog. But whenever I try to load them to the ArcMap document, I get the error:

> DBMS table not found

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer: my postgis layers had capitals in their names. I changed it and now ArcMap can load them into the document.